# jQuery stop animation

Tags: jquery

So I have a list of news items that have AJAX controls to create, edit, or delete. Upon one of these actions a small message is shown at the top confirming whatever they did. So if they add a new post, it pops up with "Added News: title". It slides down, then after 10 seconds slides up back. The problem is that if multiple actions are done before the 10 seconds is up, it animates multiple times.

For example:
Create news with title "one" - message comes down.

After 4 seconds, Create news with title "two" - message comes down.

After 6 seconds, message for "one" slides up, and then after another 4 seconds the message for "two" slides up.

I want it to only ever slide up once, so you can queue as many actions you want and then 10 seconds after the last action, it slides up.

Here's what I got:

```
$('#ajax-message').html('Added News: ' + title);
$('#ajax-message').slideDown('1000').delay('10000').slideUp('1000');
```

Comment: Can you please post some code (perhaps on jsfiddle.net) with the troubled code so we can accurately help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is use setTimeout, and each time a new action is done, clear the previous timeout and create a new one.

Something like:

```
var timerID;

...
// when an action occurs
clearTimeout(timerID);
timerID=setTimeout(function(){
   $('#ajax-message').slideUp('1000');
},10000);
```

Comment: This works except that it doesn't restart a timeout properly. For example, if I create a news and then 7 seconds later create another, the message only lasts 3 seconds.

Comment: I missed the time parameter in setTimeout.

Comment: Yeah, I had added that in - but it still happens.

Comment: I also added in `timerID=` which was missing, did you do that also?

Comment: Works for me.  See the fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/bMNSR/  the timer is obviously not great, but it gives an idea of how long ago you clicked.  every time you click the button it resets the 10 second wait.

Comment: Yeah works fine for me there too, not sure what's up. I'll use it anyway, it is only a minor quirk.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're having an issue with animation queue build up. Have you tried jQuery.stop() ?

http://api.jquery.com/stop/

To avoid this it might be better practice and more well suited if you used the jQuery.queue() / jquery.dequeue() function: http://api.jquery.com/queue/

Comment: Will stop cancel a delay?  I've found mixed reports in searching.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if #ajax_message is opened by checking it's visibility, stop() so it not slideUp again, .append() new message to current message, then do the delayed slideUp again

```
if( $('#ajax_message').is(':hidden') )
{   
    $('#ajax_message').html('AddedNews'+title).slideDown('1000').delay('10000').slideUp('1000');
}
else
{
    //is opened
    $('#ajax_message').stop().append('<br />AddedNews'+title).delay('10000').slideUp('1000');
}
```

(Untested code)

**Edit:**
Changed the way to test visibility. Thanks @kingjiv

Comment: You can use is(":hidden") instead of checking the display in css.  `if( $('#ajax_message').is(':hidden'))`